# Spontaneous Shutdown Win7

Tags: windows-7

Asus CM1745 desktop running Win7 HomePremium spontaneously shuts down. No other user besides the system owner has rights to anything within the system. No other PCs on the home network were turned on at the time of the event. Power cable is tight at the back of the desktop.

Power up is uneventful. No CPU temp monitors were installed by the user.

The system log, starting just before the shutdown, follows below, in CSV format.

What do I look for to tell me where to look next?  TY.

```
Level,Date and Time,Source,Event ID,Task Category
Information,3/22/2015 12:13:54 PM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C00000BE
Information,3/22/2015 12:13:54 PM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C0000039
Information,3/22/2015 12:13:54 PM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C0000039
Information,3/22/2015 12:13:54 PM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C0000039
Information,3/22/2015 12:11:22 PM,mbamchameleon,61440,(4096),Failed to verify the digital signature for ce\HarddiskVolume10\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\KASPERSKY LAB\KASPERSKY INTERNET SECURITY 15.0.1\AVP.EXE 
Information,3/22/2015 12:11:22 PM,mbamchameleon,61440,(4096),Failed to verify the digital signature for \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 15.0.1\avp.exe 
Information,3/22/2015 12:10:47 PM,mbamchameleon,61440,(4096),Failed to verify the digital signature for ce\HarddiskVolume10\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\KASPERSKY LAB\KASPERSKY INTERNET SECURITY 15.0.1\AVP.EXE 
Information,3/22/2015 12:10:47 PM,mbamchameleon,61440,(4096),Failed to verify the digital signature for \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 15.0.1\avp.exe 
Information,3/22/2015 12:02:36 PM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Software Protection service entered the stopped state.
Information,3/22/2015 12:02:02 PM,Service Control Manager,7045,None,"A service was installed in the system.  Service Name:  MBAMSwissArmy Service File Name:  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\MBAMSwissArmy.sys Service Type:  kernel mode driver Service Start Type:  demand start Service Account:  "
Information,3/22/2015 12:00:58 PM,EventLog,6013,None,The system uptime is 368 seconds.
Information,3/22/2015 11:58:53 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C00000BE
Information,3/22/2015 11:58:53 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C0000039
Information,3/22/2015 11:58:53 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C0000039
Information,3/22/2015 11:58:53 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C0000039
Information,3/22/2015 11:58:35 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience,206,None,The Program Compatibility Assistant service successfully performed phase two initialization.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:39 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Update service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:38 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The UPnP Device Host service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:38 AM,Microsoft-Windows-WMPNSS-Service,14206,None,Media server 'PEQUOD-PC: Pequod:' was successfully initialized and is sharing media with network media devices.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:37 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Security Center service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:37 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Media Player Network Sharing Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:37 AM,Microsoft-Windows-WMPNSS-Service,14204,None,Service 'WMPNetworkSvc' started.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:32 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Defender service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:31 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Software Protection service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:31 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Google Update Service (gupdate) service entered the stopped state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:31 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Google Update Service (gupdate) service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:29 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X64 service entered the stopped state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:29 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X64 service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:29 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The SSDP Discovery service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X86 service entered the stopped state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Microsoft .NET Framework NGEN v4.0.30319_X86 service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:27 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Background Intelligent Transfer Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:24 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Skype Updater service entered the stopped state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:16 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:16 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:16 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:16 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:16 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:16 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:57:16 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:56:39 AM,mbamchameleon,61440,(4096),Failed to verify the digital signature for ddiskVolume10\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\KASPERSKY LAB\KASPERSKY INTERNET SECURITY 15.0.1\X64\WMI64.EXE 
Information,3/22/2015 11:56:39 AM,mbamchameleon,61440,(4096),Failed to verify the digital signature for \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 15.0.1\x64\wmi64.exe 
Information,3/22/2015 11:56:29 AM,Service Control Manager,7045,None,"A service was installed in the system.  Service Name:  MBAMSwissArmy Service File Name:  C:\Windows\system32\drivers\MBAMSwissArmy.sys Service Type:  kernel mode driver Service Start Type:  demand start Service Account:  "
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:46 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Search service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:45 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Application Experience service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:44 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:44 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:44 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C000000D
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:36 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Network Connections service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:30 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Driver Foundation - User-mode Driver Framework service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:30 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The WinHTTP Web Proxy Auto-Discovery Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:29 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The IPsec Policy Agent service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Computer Browser service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service entered the stopped state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7042,None,"The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service was successfully sent a stop control.   The reason specified was: 0x40030011 [Operating System: Network Connectivity (Planned)]   Comment: None"
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Portable Device Enumerator Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Diagnostic System Host service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Human Interface Device Access service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:28 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Network List Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:27 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Diagnostic Service Host service entered the running state. Error,3/22/2015 11:55:27 AM,Service Control Manager,7026,None,"The following boot-start or system-start driver(s) failed to load:  Uim_VIM"
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:27 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Server service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:26 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The VPN Unlimited Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:26 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The IP Helper service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:25 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Management Instrumentation service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:24 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Adaptive Brightness service entered the stopped state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:23 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Distributed Link Tracking Client service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:23 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Image Acquisition (WIA) service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:23 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Superfetch service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:23 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Skype Updater service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:23 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Network Location Awareness service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:23 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Adaptive Brightness service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:23 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Protexis Licensing V2 service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:23 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The MBAMService service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:22 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Program Compatibility Assistant Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:22 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Application-Experience,201,None,The Program Compatibility Assistant service started successfully.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:21 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The MBAMScheduler service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:19 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The IKE and AuthIP IPsec Keying Modules service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:19 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Everything service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:19 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Encrypting File System (EFS) service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:18 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Diagnostic Policy Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:18 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Cryptographic Services service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:18 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Skype Click to Call PNR Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:16 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Skype Click to Call Updater service entered the running state. Warning,3/22/2015 11:55:15 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Wininit,11,None,Custom dynamic link libraries are being loaded for every application. The system administrator should review the list of libraries to ensure they are related to trusted applications.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:14 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Kaspersky Anti-Virus Service 15.0.1 service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:13 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The AMD FUEL Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:11 AM,mbamchameleon,61440,(4096),Failed to verify the digital signature for ce\HarddiskVolume10\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\KASPERSKY LAB\KASPERSKY INTERNET SECURITY 15.0.1\AVP.EXE 
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:11 AM,mbamchameleon,61440,(4096),Failed to verify the digital signature for \??\C:\Program Files (x86)\Kaspersky Lab\Kaspersky Internet Security 15.0.1\avp.exe 
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:11 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The AMD FUEL Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:10 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Workstation service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:10 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C00000FB
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:10 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C00000FB
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:10 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Winlogon,7001,(1101),User Logon Notification for Customer Experience Improvement Program
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:10 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Firewall service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:10 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C00000A3
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:10 AM,mbamchameleon,61703,(4352),Mbamchameleon Failed to obtain file name information - C00000A3
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:10 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Base Filtering Engine service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:09 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Print Spooler service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:09 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Task Scheduler service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Shell Hardware Detection service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The DNS Client service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The DHCP Client service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Microsoft-Windows-DHCPv6-Client,51046,Service State Event,DHCPv6 client service is started
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Dhcp-Client,50036,Service State Event,DHCPv4 client service is started
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The TCP/IP NetBIOS Helper service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Network Store Interface Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Security Accounts Manager service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Desktop Window Manager Session Manager service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The System Event Notification Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The COM+ Event System service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Group Policy Client service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The User Profile Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Themes service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:08 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Audio service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:07 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Audio Endpoint Builder service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:07 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Font Cache Service service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:07 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Multimedia Class Scheduler service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:07 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Windows Event Log service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:07 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The AMD External Events Utility service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:06 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Remote Procedure Call (RPC) service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:06 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The RPC Endpoint Mapper service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:06 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The DCOM Server Process Launcher service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:06 AM,Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager,6,None,"File System Filter 'MBAMProtector' (6.1, ?2014?-?09?-?03T10:50:25.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager."
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:06 AM,Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager,6,None,"File System Filter 'luafv' (6.1, ?2009?-?07?-?13T16:26:13.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager."
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:06 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Power service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:06 AM,Microsoft-Windows-UserPnp,20010,(7010),"One or more of the Plug and Play service's subsystems has changed state.   PlugPlay install subsystem enabled: 'true'  PlugPlay caching subsystem enabled: 'true'  "
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:06 AM,Service Control Manager,7036,None,The Plug and Play service entered the running state.
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:59 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power,26,(4),"Processor 3 in group 0 exposes the following:  1 idle state(s) 6 performance state(s) 0 throttle state(s)"
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:59 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power,26,(4),"Processor 2 in group 0 exposes the following:  1 idle state(s) 6 performance state(s) 0 throttle state(s)"
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:59 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power,26,(4),"Processor 1 in group 0 exposes the following:  1 idle state(s) 6 performance state(s) 0 throttle state(s)"
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:59 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Processor-Power,26,(4),"Processor 0 in group 0 exposes the following:  1 idle state(s) 6 performance state(s) 0 throttle state(s)" Warning,3/22/2015 11:54:58 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP,219,(212),The driver \Driver\WUDFRd failed to load for the device Root\PARAGONBLOCKDEVICE\0001.
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:58 AM,Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode,10114,Startup of the UMDF reflector,"The UMDF reflector was unable to complete startup because the WUDFPf service was not found.  This service may be started later during boot, at which point Windows will attempt to start the device again." Warning,3/22/2015 11:54:58 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-PnP,219,(212),The driver \Driver\WUDFRd failed to load for the device Root\PARAGONBLOCKDEVICE\0000.
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:58 AM,Microsoft-Windows-DriverFrameworks-UserMode,10114,Startup of the UMDF reflector,"The UMDF reflector was unable to complete startup because the WUDFPf service was not found.  This service may be started later during boot, at which point Windows will attempt to start the device again." Critical,3/22/2015 11:54:58 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-Power,41,(63),"The system has rebooted without cleanly shutting down first. This error could be caused if the system stopped responding, crashed, or lost power unexpectedly."
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:58 AM,Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager,6,None,"File System Filter 'mbamchameleon' (6.1, ?2014?-?08?-?18T07:53:30.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager."
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:58 AM,Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager,6,None,"File System Filter 'KLIF' (6.0, ?2014?-?12?-?16T07:08:28.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager." Error,3/22/2015 11:54:57 AM,volmgr,46,None,Crash dump initialization failed!
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:07 AM,EventLog,6013,None,The system uptime is 17 seconds.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:07 AM,EventLog,6005,None,The Event log service was started.
Information,3/22/2015 11:55:07 AM,EventLog,6009,None,Microsoft (R) Windows (R) 6.01. 7601 Service Pack 1 Multiprocessor Free. Error,3/22/2015 11:55:07 AM,EventLog,6008,None,The previous system shutdown at 11:54:05 AM on ?3/?22/?2015 was unexpected.
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:51 AM,Microsoft-Windows-FilterManager,6,None,"File System Filter 'FileInfo' (6.1, ?2009?-?07?-?13T16:34:25.000000000Z) has successfully loaded and registered with Filter Manager."
Information,3/22/2015 11:54:50 AM,Microsoft-Windows-Kernel-General,12,None,The operating system started at system time ?2015?-?03?-?22T18:54:50.109999400Z.
```

Comment: This also happens in *recovery mode*? And, recently was updated some hardware drive?

Comment: Did you check the cpu temperature?

Comment: I reformated your log (because it was unreadable like you pasted it). Could the problem be the recent installation of Malwarebytes? I see that a service (MBAMSwissArmy) is installed (multiple times) just before restart and it could be the cause of restart. (You could try uninstalling everything from malwarebytes and see if these lines remain.) Also... is this still happening and how often?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wiped out Windows 7, installed Windows 8.1, problem solved and has not recurred in the week since.